# Applying Spacy word vectorisation to list of lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, spacy

I'm trying to apply a function to each tuple element in the following structure (list of lists containing tuples). The function is a Spacy function, and each element of each tuple is of type 'spacy.tokens.span.Span'

```
import spacy
tuple_vectors = []

for list_item in tuples_list: #iterate through list items
    for tuple_ in list_item: #there are sometimes multiple tuples in each list item
        for tuple_element in tuple_: #iterate through tuple elements

            #tuple_element to Spacy doc
            tuple_element_vector = tuple_element.vector #get vector
            tuple_vectors = tuple_vectors.append(tuple_element_vector) #update tuple_vectors
```

My current implementation returns:

> ---> 11             tuple_vectors = tuple_vectors.append(tuple_element_vector) #update tuple_vectors
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

```
tuples_list = [[(Sky proposal, is, matter), (Sky proposal, is, Mays 
spokesman)], [(Women, 
lag, Intel report)], [(Amazon, expected, to unveil)], [(Goldman Sachs, raising, 
billion)], [(MHP, opens, books)], [(Disney, hurls, magic), (Disney, hurls, 
moolah)], [(Amazon, offering, loans), (Amazon, offering, to)], [(JPMorgan, 
seeks, billion), (JPMorgan, seeks, WaMu claims)], [(Comcast, accuses, 
Discovery)], [(Boeing, sees, sales)], [(BRIEFNetflix Inc, reports, earnings)], 
[(Broadcom deal, may stunt, Valley investment)], [(Apple, sell, iPads)], [(oil, 
pull, Street)], [(Fed, tells, Goldman), (Fed, tells, to improve)], [(ideas, 
undermine, Brexit), (ideas, undermine, Facebook)] ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code says

```
tuple_vectors = tuple_vectors.append(tuple_element_vector)
```

The `append` method doesn't return the list, it returns `None`, hence your error.
In effect, you reset `tuple_vectors` to `None` at this point.

Change this to

```
tuple_vectors.append(tuple_element_vector)
```